# VDI errors but backups are successful

Tags: sql-server, backup

Our monitoring tools are showing SQLVDI errors, I think they're coming from the Event Viewer only. But the backups are showing successful in the SQL Server log files and we've successfully restored the backups.

The events look like this:

```
Event Log Module Status: 0 
The Last Record Number of the eventlog type that current event entry belongs to: 0 
# of duplicate events: 20.00 
Events Source: SQLVDI 
Category: None 
Event ID: 1 
User (If Applicable): N/A 
Event Description: SQLVDI: 
Loc=TriggerAbort. 
Desc=invoked. 
ErrorCode=(0). 
Process=3056. 
Thread=7460. 
Server. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. 
VD=Global\{08771828-3181-438B-A554-E02DA96EB3F2}7_SQLVDIMemoryName_0. 
Event Log Name: Application 
Event Log Type: error 
Event Log Date Time: 2018-05-11 09:04:06 
Notification Generated By: *0 Minute Delay - Priority 4 The Windows Event Log - SQL 2008 service transitioned from a Normal state to a Failed state at 2018-05-11 09:16:21 .
```

Can I safely stop monitoring SQLVDI errors?

Thank you for your time,

Thomas

Comment: Can you include the specific examples of the errors? My worry is that you've got backups that are "succeeding" but the writes to the backup file aren't working out as planned.

Comment: Hi Brent
Event Log Module Status: 0
The Last Record Number of the eventlog type that current event entry belongs to: 0
# of duplicate events: 20.00 Events
Source: SQLVDI
Category: None
Event ID: 1
User (If Applicable): N/A
Event Description: SQLVDI: Loc=TriggerAbort. Desc=invoked. ErrorCode=(0). Process=3056. Thread=7460. Server. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. VD=Global\{08771828-3181-438B-A554-E02DA96EB3F2}7_SQLVDIMemoryName_0.
Event Log Name: Application
Event Log Type: error
Event Log Date Time: 2018-05-11 09:04:06

Comment: Notification Generated By: *0 Minute Delay - Priority 4

The Windows Event Log - SQL 2008 service transitioned from a Normal state to a Failed state at 2018-05-11 09:16:21 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just me, but no, I wouldn't ignore an event that said:

```
SQL 2008 service transitioned from a Normal state to a Failed state at 2018-05-11 09:16:21
```

That would be the kind of event I'd pay a little deeper attention to. If you Google for text involved in that error, you get [KB articles like 2615182](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2615182/windows-server-backup-may-fail-because-of-the-sql-vss-writer), suggesting that it's a Windows backup failing, not a SQL Server one.